# Use a normal link to submit a form

Tags: html, css, forms, hyperlink, submit

I want to submit a form. But I am not going the basic way of using a input button with submit type but a **a** link.

The image below shows why. I am using image links to save/submit the form. Because I have standart css markup for image links I don't want to use input submit buttons.

I tried to apply *onClick="document.formName.submit()"* to the a element but I would prefer a html method.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: use button and css it to display the image or use javascript, there's no real way to make simple href to submit  a form without javascript.

Comment: i second that, unfortunately these isnt an easy way w/o javascript

Comment: Your reason for doing this sounds like a false economy.  Better to just come up with a standard css for submit buttons and use forms the way they were designed to be used.  There are a pile of button css techniques describe here: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2009/06/24-essential-submit-button-enhancements.html

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Two ways. Either create a button and style it so it looks like a link with css, or create a link and use `onclick="this.closest('form').submit();return false;"`.

Comment: Aaaaaaaand here's a reference for how to style a button as a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link

Comment: note that `form.submit()` will not work without JavaScript

Comment: @baptx even old smart phones have enabled javascript

Comment: @MahdiJazini a lot of people disable JavaScript by default which can be intrusive and affect performance in some cases. If JavaScript fails, it can break the whole website (e.g. using a CDN without local fallback and the third-party domain is blocked). If there is an HTML error, you can still use the website. Developers should follow progressive enhancement principle instead.

Comment: If you want to support users without javascript, do the first option described in this answer, style a button like a link. For instance `input[type=submit].link { border: none; background: none; display: inline; color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }` and `<input type=submit class="link" />`

Comment: This will refresh the page if you use Ajax to submit even with the event.preventDefault()...

Comment: Anchor links do not have a `.form` property. Plus you have to return false or else the browser will follow the link instead of submit the form.

Comment: If using jQuery you should do this: `<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();return false;">Submit</a>`

Comment: jQuery should be used only when necessary. In this case, if the code is in another place and link is fetched by jQuery and using .on('click'), good. But in your example, it is better to leave jQuery. `this.closest('form').submit();return false` if faster and less code.

Answer (score 97):

You can't really do this without some form of scripting to the best of my knowledge.

```
<form id="my_form">
<!-- Your Form -->    
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); return false;">submit</a>
</form>
```

Example from [Here](http://snipplr.com/view/5911/submit-a-form-with-an-anchor-tag-link/).

Comment: and dear visitors... don't forget to set the >>> id="my_form"  it's id not name :D

Comment: This should be the best and explicit answer, thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Just styling an `input type="submit"` like this worked for me:

```css
.link-button { 
     background: none;
     border: none;
     color: #1a0dab;
     text-decoration: underline;
     cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="link-button" />
```

Tested in Chrome, IE 7-9, Firefox

Comment: just for the record: you should select the appropriate `input` element using CSS selectors without attaching a class to the HTML element.

Comment: Although your comment is the preferred way, this is not always possible

Comment: Why is that the preferred way?

Comment: It's a semi-established coding practice, generally leaves behind cleaner html... but it's not a huge deal

Comment: This answer doesn't depend on javascript either which is one less thing to worry about

Comment: See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11):

You are using images to submit.. so you can simply use an `type="image"` input "button":

```
<input type="image" src="yourimage.png" name="yourinputname" value="yourinputvalue" />
```

Comment: ...or a `<button>` element with an `<img/>` element in it.

Comment: Here's the MDN link for this in case anyone else wanted a source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
<input type="image" src=".."/>
```

or:

```
<button type="send"><img src=".."/> + any html code</button>
```

plus some CSS

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, there is no solution with pure HTML to submit a form with a link (`a`) tag. The standard HTML accepts only buttons or images. As some other collaborators have said, one can simulate the appearance of a link using a button, but I guess that's not the purpose of the question.

IMHO, I believe that the proposed and accepted solution does not work.

I have tested it on a form and the browser didn't find the reference to the form.

So it is possible to solve it using a single line of JavaScript, using `this` object, which references the element being clicked, which is a child node of the form, that needs to be submitted. So `this.parentNode` is the form node. After it's just calling `submit()` method in that form. It's no necessary research from whole document to find the right form.

```
<form action="http://www.greatsolutions.com.br/indexint.htm"                   
   method="get">
    <h3> Enter your name</h3>
    First Name <input type="text"  name="fname"  size="30"><br>
    Last Name <input type="text" name="lname" size="30"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();"> Submit here</a>
</form>
```

Suppose that I enter with my own name:

[image: Filled form]

I've used `get` in form method attribute because it's possible to see the right parameters in the URL at loaded page after submit.

```
http://www.greatsolutions.com.br/indexint.htm?fname=Paulo&lname=Buchsbaum
```

This solution obviously applies to any tag that accepts the `onclick` event or some similar event.

`this` is a excellent choice to recover the context together with [`event` variable](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) (available in all major browsers and IE9 onwards) that can be used directly or passed as an argument to a function.

In this case, replace the line with `a` tag by the line below, using the property `target`, that indicates the element that has started the event.

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.target.parentNode.submit();"> Submit here</a>
```

Comment: @Nathan, I do not have much practice of writing in `Stackoverflow`. I hope that your corrections help me to improve my style. My English is not good either.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
OnClick="document.getElementById('formID_NOT_NAME').SUBMIT()"