# need to open url and pass hidden parameters (post request), primefaces

Tags: jsf, url, post, primefaces, parameters

I am using primefaces. I need to open URL from my UI and pass login credentials and other parameters with that URL. How can I send the request to URL and pass parameters which are not visible. I tried the following:

1)

```
<p:menuitem value="report" url="http://someUrl" icon="ui-icon-document" ajax="false"
    target="_blank" includeViewParams="true">
    <f:param id="decorate" name="decorate" value="no" />
</p:menuitem>
```

2)

```
<h:outputLink value="http://someUrl" ajax="false" target="_blank" includeViewParams="true">
    link
    <f:viewParam id="decorate" name="decorate" value="no" />
</h:outputLink>
```

In these two cases I am trying to pass 'decorate' parameter. It is opening the URL but the parameter is not being passed.

Comment: `<h:outputlink/>` does not have ajax attribute so you can not write ajax="false"

Comment: It's not a very good idea to send `secured parameters` like `login info` with a `GET` request which you are using now with `<h:outputLink/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML does not allow you to send POST parameters via a hyperlink, which is what an `<h:outputLink>` renders. You can use a `<p:commandLink>`, as explained below, to call JavaScript; it should look something like this:

```
<p:commandLink type="button" onclick="<javascript here>">
```

Here are two separate ways to achieve this:

- [Use a normal link to submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form)
- [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)