# I Don't want ?lan=AL code in my url php?

Tags: php

I want to change the language without showing the url: 
http://myweb.com/?lan=AL
or
http://myweb.com/about-us?lan=AL

How can it be done in background, not to show in url.
This is the code below.

```
require('_inc_lang/lan_en.php');
require('_inc_lang/lan_al.php');
require('_inc_lang/lan_de.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['lan'])){
session_start();
}

    if(isset($_GET['lan'])){
    $_SESSION['lan'] = $_GET['lan'];
    }

    $lan = isset($_SESSION['lan']) ? $_SESSION['lan'] : 'al';
    switch ($lan) {
    case 'al':
    $TEXT = $TEXT_AL;
    break;
    case 'de':
    $TEXT = $TEXT_DE;
    break;
    case 'en':
    $TEXT = $TEXT_EN;
    break;
}
```

Comment: What logical reason exists why you wouldn't want to do it using GET method? It's so easy to implement, and it's even easier to understand by you and your user.

Comment: Can it be done with Javascript, because the user should click for a language. <a href="?lan=EN" >ENGLISH</a>

Answer (score 2):

You can do it based on the browser language

```
<?php
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "de":
        $TEXT = $TEXT_DE;
        break;
    case "en":
        $TEXT = $TEXT_EN;
        break;
    case "al":
        $TEXT = $TEXT_AL;
        break;        
    default:
        $TEXT = $TEXT_EN;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't. I cannot count the amount of times I've gotten annoyed at a website/application for being in Danish just because I have a Danish OS/browser, or let alone reside in Denmark. At *least* give me the option to change it.

Comment: Let me know one of your sites. My language is set to Klingon :)

Comment: James Anderson on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101607/why-do-websites-have-to-ask-language-and-country-when-the-browser-can-tell-them basically lists why we reheally should not use the browsers language to auto set. Its massively annoying.

Comment: @NeilMasters Everything on my computer is set in English. However, because I am located in Peru, Google insists on presenting all its pages in Spanish so they seem to be using ip-based detection instead of the http header (unless my isp changes headers without my knowledge of course...). So for a default - with the option to change it - this could work.

Answer (score 1):

Change from GET to POST.

```
<form method="post">
    ..button/select/whatever have you
</form>

if(isset($_POST) && /* sanitise */)
    $_SESSION['lan'] = $_POST['lan'];
```

Code needs a tidy up but you can do that yourself :) Is this what you are looking for?

Edit:
Absolutely totally must use a link or you will explode? The following SO pages will magically show you how!

[Use a normal link to submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form)

[How to submit a form with JavaScript by clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799533/how-to-submit-a-form-with-javascript-by-clicking-a-link)

Comment: Can it be done with Javascript, because the user should click for a language.
<a href="?lan=EN" >ENGLISHT</a>

Comment: I think it is not working. Better solution is to use javascript. If you can help me with that, it will be more easy for me. When I will click the link for language, then the website will turn to that language.

Answer (score 1):

You're already copying the language choice to the session, so if it is found in the URL, just location: to the version without the URL:

```
if(isset($_GET['lan'])){
    $_SESSION['lan'] = $_GET['lan'];
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']);
}
```

Edit: note that I added variable `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']` instead of hard coded location; now it will work regardless of where it is called (`SCRIPT_URI` will give you server/page without query string)

Comment: As I understand it, OP wants to remove the use of the lan from the URI. Your solution would not remove it but would redirect after setting.

Comment: @NeilMasters  Looking at the question, it repeatedly mentions not wanting the query string in the URL, nothing about removing functionality from the code. A form post solution introduces other complications, like the inability to link from another site to a specific language version.

Comment: you raise a valid point and my hat has been tipped. OP will have to utilise both methods if he wants users to link to language based content. [edit] Cant @your name :(