# Make link submit identically to default button behavior

Tags: html, css, button

Sorry if this seems redundant. I have read through quite a few posts and cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this. I need an element that behaves like a button but I thought to use a css class object instead. I have found a number of references showing how to do this by making `href="#"` and adding javascript command.

```
<p><input name="Test" type="Button" value="Click" /></p>
```

However, due to the server side software I am using I need to exactly duplicate the behavior of the button in order to make it submit my form.

I am guessing it is something obvious like:

```
<p><a class="button" href="#" onclick="submit()">Click</a></p>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference to the `form` element, and then call the submit:

```
<p><a class="button" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myFormId').submit()">Click</a></p>
```

Though you should not be using inline event delegation:

HTML:

```
<p><a class="button" href="#" id="submit-anchor">Click</a></p>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("submit-anchor").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">Click</a>
```

If you have one `form` in the document, else change `0` accordingly.

OR

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="document.forms['formName'].submit();">Click</a>
```

Uses `form` name.

OR

```
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formID').submit();">Click</a>
```

Uses `form` id.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `"form.submit();"` 
you should check out this question: [Use a normal link to submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form)