# Send form after clicking on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form and i want to submit it using a link. The form has to be sent to the `href` of the link. This is my idea:

Set a click event to the link `tag` which does the following:

- Blocks the default action of following the link.
- Edits the form by setting the action to the href of the link.
- Submits the form using jquery submit() function.

I am looking for a solution where i don't have to change my html, only javascript.

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
jQuery('.row_header').find('td').each(function(){
    var cell = jQuery(this);
    cell.find('a').each(function(){
        //Get last link in cell. There is only one
        linkObject = jQuery(this);
    });     

    //Gets form
    var form = jQuery('#searchForm');

    if(typeof linkObject !== 'undefined'){
        //Get location url for form
        var url = linkObject.attr('href');

        linkObject.click(function(e){
            //Prevent default (following link)
            e.preventDefault(); 
            //Set location from link as form action     
            form.attr('action',url);
            //Submits form
            form.submit();

        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" value="myValue">
    <input type="submit" name="mySubmit" value="mySubmitValue">
</form>

<table>
    <tr class="row_header"><td><a href="myLocation.php">The Link </a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the `action` *of your form* the `href` *of your link* when it's clicked, try the following:

```
 $( "#myLink" ).click(function() {
   var form =  $( "#searchForm" ); 
   form.action=$(this).attr('href');
   console.log(form.action);
   form.submit();
 });
```

Here is a [**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x98vwkx4/).

Comment: Thank you. The console logs the right url, so the action is set. However, the form still does not submit.

Comment: No it does, but the problem is with the url  I changed the href to http://www.w3schools.com/ and it submit correctly see [**the fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/x98vwkx4/3/) and try it locally with your url and it will work fine.

Comment: I don't get an error. But it simply follows the link, no postdata is sent.

Comment: You just need to add `method="POST"` to your form.

Comment: I already did, just forgot in the example. Doesnt matter. I added form="post" to your fiddle, and changed the location to my local address on a site with only var_dump($_POST) on it and it prints an empty array. It does not send post data.

Answer (score 2):

you see where is your link object defined. There is `linkObject` which is inside the `(` `)`.

have you defined this variable?

You have used `a` element which would take you to the link. so you must use the attribute which starts like this `data-` and you can make it to look like `data-href1=' your link'` ard set the attribut `href` as `#`.

Simply your `a` element should look like:

```
<a href='#' data-href1 ='your link'> click </a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use "#" because they may force the webpage to go to the top.  "href='javascript:void(0)'" is safer.

Comment: Theres should indeed be a var linkObject; above row 2, but i added it and it doesnt work.
And i want to avoid changing my html.

Comment: Leaving it blank is not good practice.  If it's blank, then why put it?

Comment: Im looking for a solution that does not involve changing html

Answer (score 1):

One option is to style the a form submit button like a link. You can see that here:

[How to make button look like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link)

Or have the link use javascript to submit the form. Like here:

[Use a normal link to submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form)

Both will do what you need.

Comment: I want to use a normal link, but restyle a button. And the second one is kind of what i am trying to do here, with adding a submit(). However, i cannot get it working

Answer (score 1):

JQuery submit function binds a handler to the submit event.

you can use AJAX, for example to send data

Comment: I don't want to use ajax, i want the the page to refresh and submit the form like pressing on a button would do.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I still have no idea why, but for some reason .submit() doesn't call the submit function. My workaround is finding the submit button and triggering a click on that:

```
form.find('#submitId').trigger('click');
```

in stead of

```
form.submit()
```

And

```
 <input type="submit" name="mySubmit" id="submitId" value="mySubmitValue">
```

in stead of

```
 <input type="submit" name="mySubmit" value="mySubmitValue">
```

Altough editing the html is not necessary, but then you have to edit the find() function to find the submit on name or type. I also changed my code a bit while looking for the result. Here is the final JS:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.row_header').find('td').each(function(){

        var linkObject = jQuery(this).find('a');

        if(typeof linkObject !== 'undefined'){

            linkObject.click(function(e){
                //Prevent following the link
                e.preventDefault();
                //Get url
                var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');     
                //Get form              
                var form = jQuery('#searchForm');
                //Change form action
                form.action = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                //Click submit button
                form.find('#submitId').trigger('click');
            });
        }
    });
});
```