# define f.submit as a link not a button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of members and for each member I use a form_for so that the member_id does not appear in the url (I know I could use cookies, but they can be manipulated).

```
<%= form_for pat, :url => {:controller => "clinics", :action => "store_in_session"} do |f| %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "pat_id", pat %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "edit_right", edit_right %>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit pat, :class => "button-link" %></div>
<%end%>
```

But instead of a button I want to have just a link. I know I should modify css somehow, but I came out with:

```
.button-link {
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
color: blue;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But I still can see that it is a button and I just need a link. How can I do that?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form

Comment: checked, did not find the answer

Comment: @Tonja it didn't work with js?