# Vaadin - Open URL in browser with POST

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In my Vaadin 14 application, I want to open a website with the appropriate parameters when the user clicks on a button. The resource needs the parameters as the body of the post request. How can I open a new URL in Vaadin with a post request?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it. Have you checked
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286466/use-a-normal-link-to-submit-a-form
?

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to a page as a POST request does in practice mean that a "traditional" `<form>` should be submitted. Vaadin doesn't have high-level support for submitting forms in that way, but you can use low-level APIs such as `new Element("form")` to create a server-side representation for the form itself, configure how it should work (e.g. defining the `action`). Correspondingly, you can also use `new Element("input")` to create hidden input fields with the data you want to submit in the body (assuming it should be posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) and then submitting the form either through regular HTML button or through JS using `formElement.callJsFunction("submit")`.