# Button which looks like link

Tags: asp.net, css, button

Hi I have a requirement where I'm not allowed to use javascript on the page. I had some `asp:LinkButtons` but these appeared to use javascript so I replaced them with buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="titleButton" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="downloadButtonClick" Text="Download" CssClass="ButtonAsLink" />
```

with css:

```
.ButtonAsLink
{
  background-color:transparent;
  border:none;
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold
}
```

This works as I was wanting but the Text of the button does not line up with the labels in the same column due to the margins between the edge of the button and the text.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me how to set the button text margin to zero?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make button look like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.ButtonAsLink{
   background-color:transparent;
   border:none;
   color:blue;
   cursor:pointer;
   text-decoration:underline;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

Set the element padding to 0px if you want to remove all padding or you can use the attribute like this.

```
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

Of course you can have any positive numerical value in place of zero. the orientation of the padding in this attribute as it relates to the numerical valuesis:

padding: top right bottom left

Last note: Margin is the spacing around an element and other elements around it. Padding is the spacing of the area within an element (e.g. text within a )

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing out the difference between margins and padding.

Comment: note:  font-weight:bold  needs a semi-colon after it.  SO doesn't allow me to make one character edits.

Answer (score 2):

What about setting the margins and padding in your style?

Comment: you should use a css reset file to alleviate such presentational problems

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to your CSS properties. Also you can try forcing: `display: inline;`

Answer (score 1):

Here, I put a little something together that might work for you. It's not perfect, but could be a starting point for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gj9R6/1/