# Submit a form using <a> anchor element, without javascript

Tags: html, forms

How to replace the submit button with a link without using javascript ? is there any way to add the submit attribute to a link ? because the form will not be sent by a simple link without "submit".

```
<form:form action="/getPage" >
     <div class="buttons">

         <a class="link" href=""> 
           <img src="icon.png" />
         </a>

     </div>         
</form:form>
```

I work in an application web so if i use javascript the link will not be mapped by the server ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link

Comment: If you make your *button* a link, make sure Google and other search engines don't go through your page.  You don't want a *delete link* triggered by the search engines.

Comment: The real question is: why must you use `<a>` to submit the form? What's wrong with `<input>` or `<button>`??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
button {
    background:none!important;
    border:none; 
    padding:0!important;
    /*border is optional*/
    border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button>your button that looks like a link</button>
```

Answer (score 29):

You can not submit a form using an `<a>` tag alone. You **will** need some type of  javascript to assist, if you insist on using the `<a>` tag:

`<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Submit the Form</a>`

or

`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit()">Submit the Form</a>`

or super hack:

`<a href="backendPage.php?param1=yes&param2=no">Submit the Form</a>`, then on backendPage.php you can use `$_GET` requests to process information, and redirect the visitor to the intended page. But that's a horrible idea haha

Comment: Hay hello man, I used this method and it worked fine, but didnt work when I changed href value to empty string (href=" ") can you tell me what is the significance of the #....

Comment: Hi @fazkan, the`href="#whatever"` tells the browser to change the hash in the URL, which usually means no page reload (excluding angular, etc.). An empty `href` attribute will be the same as pointing to the current page which will reload the page. Alternatively, you could remove the `href` attribute completely and use CSS `cursor:pointer` to make the mouse hover look like a link.

Answer (score 8):

This can achieve the same effort and it looks like  `<a>`

**Note:** `btn` `btn-link` comes from `bootstrap`

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="submit"><img src="icon.png" /></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way out. Using this method you can use any element to submit a form.
Following is an example:

```
<span onclick="$('#submit').trigger('click')" style="cursor:pointer;">
     anything
</span>
```

Add a hidden submit button:

```
 <input style="display:none;" type="submit" id="submit"/>
```

This will behave exactly as actual submit button.