# ASP.NET MVC 4 Default _LoginPartial template Logout not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have been fiddling around with the _Layout and _PartialLayouts of the default MVC 4 templates and suddenly the 'Logout' feature in the '_PartialLogin' doc has stopeed working. To give you more info, the _LoginPartial.cshtml is called from the _NavBar.cshtml which in turn is called from the _Layout.cshtml

The code of the _LoginPartial.cshtml is:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>
    <p>Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }</p>
</text>
}
```

The code from the _NavBar.cshtml is:

```
<form class ="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="/account/login">
    <div class ="form-group">
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
</form>
```

The code from the _Layout.cshtml is:

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_Navbar")
    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    @RenderBody()
    <div class="container">
```

I get that maybe the problem is the javascript has been disabled unintentionally somehow. Am I missing some script tags maybe? Or is it something in the previous class where I called the _PartialLogin from??

Comment: Is there still a form with the id `logoutForm` which executes a post to a logout action on the page?

Comment: Yes. I have only changed some of the lines in the '_Layout' form and the '_PartialLogin' form

Comment: @HenkMollema help please :)

Comment: Can you show (at least the relevant parts) the layout file? Also, what error are you receiving?

Comment: @HenkMollema There is no error, it just has no response when I click the Logout link - Although I even changed it to `@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })` and the redirect does not work. Is it because I am calling the _LoginPartial.cshtml in the _NavBar.cshtml which is being called from the _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: rant: Microsoft should **really stop using crappy code**. What's wrong with a `<button>` tag ? I don't understand why someone take the time to make a logout as a post request (as it should) and then write some stupid JavaScript click function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not answering your question ( *you already solved the problem* ) but I think this greatly improves the code:

change this line :

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
```

with this one:

```
<button class="btn btn-link">Log off</button>
```

also the id on the form is not needed with this change.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too - because we are also using bootstrap.

This worked fine in Chrome:

`<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>`

But to get it working on Explorer, the solution was to move the javascript to the onclick attribute:

`<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17078223

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem...

You cannot put the javascript text in a `<form>` tag. It will not work as the bootstrap messes with it then.

It doesnt matter how many times you call the partialLayouts within eachother - just be careful which tags you embed the javascript in