# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

[Here is a picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe2Cp.jpg) This error appeard after I made some changed to my project. When you press the button it's supposed to go to a controller for logging a user of the website. I remade my layout to bootstrap and changed/deleted alot of the CSS belonging to the site. This might be related but not sure how. Here is the code for the button:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
} else {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be occurring?

Comment: `getElementById('logoutForm')` is null, do check if the form exists

Comment: Use view source to verify that your Logoff form dos have the id rendered

Comment: @Marthijn @rene It seems like the logoff isent a form in the new version, apparent by this: http://i.imgur.com/hKBdtty.png . In my old version I also had this line of code in a css file: `#logoutForm {
    display: inline;
}` . Should I readd the CSS or what could be making the form not exist?

Comment: The `id` attribute is missing on the `<form>` in the new version.

Comment: @Marthijn I seem to have found a duplicate thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348810/asp-net-mvc-4-default-loginpartial-template-logout-not-working . Do you have any tips on getting this to work? I must have the `_loginPartial` inside the `Form` or else the partial login will be placed a bad position.

Comment: In that thread they say JavaScript in a form does not work, I have no experience with that. You can also change the `<a href..` for an `<input type="submit" />`, or use the jQuery solution below by @Khalid Abuhakmeh

Answer (score 2):

I would assume your problem is on this line.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
```

Check your pages source, and I would be that your action looks something like this on your form.

```
action="Account/LogOff?id=logoutForm"
```

Solution:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
```

That should fix it for you :)

Update:

You can switch the code around to make it work differently, but still work.

Option 1:

paste this at the end of your Layout file.

```
<script>$(function() {
    $('#logoutForm a').on('click', function () {
          $('#logoutForm').submit();
     });
</script>
```

Option 2:

Change the  tag to a

```
<button type="submit">Log Off</button> <!-- no JavaScript -->
```

Option 3:

```
<!-- I think this will work -->
<a onclick="document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log Off</a>
```

I personally like option 2, because you are just using a submit button like you are supposed to, instead of JavaScript.

Update #2:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit">Log Out</button>
}
```

Should produce:

```
<form action="/Account/LogOff" method="POST" id="logoutForm">
   <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerification" value="***" />
   <button type="submit">Log Out </button>
</form>
```

Take note of the **action** and the **method** attributes. Additionally make sure to remove the **text** tags from your code as they are meant to force Razor syntax to accept whatever is between them as text and not Razor syntax.

Comment: Could you "inspect the page" using the chrome tools and paste the html you get for the form tag. Just the form tag would be helpful.

Comment: As I said in the above comments, there is no form for the logout. You can see it how it should look (the old version), and how it looks now (new version) here: http://i.imgur.com/hKBdtty.png .

I have take a screenshot of the html as it is now on the form: http://i.imgur.com/lyKmYe8.png . I've tried all the three methods you posted but none work. The only one that gives a response is method 2 which refreshes the site and gives a long url with a request verification token in it. The other 2 gives the same error as before "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null".

Comment: Your form doesn't have an action="" so it is posting to the current page. Something is goofed with your routing. Additionally your form has not method (which should be POST). Does your code have the <text> tags?