# How can I make my submit button not look like a button?

Tags: css, forms

In my form I have a submit button:

```
<button name ="sort" value="sort" type="submit">&#9660;</button>
```

The button looks like a "button". This is not what I want, I would simply like the button look like this:

▼

So this means without any style, only the black arrow. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make button look like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367409/how-to-make-button-look-like-a-link)

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason a "button" type exists is so you can take advantage of the existing API, and give it multiple states without any extra effort.  To override that and make it as plain as possible doesn't make a lot of sense.  Why don't you just make a GIF with an "onClick"?  It's just as easy.

Comment: To answer the question you actually asked - Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No, I do not want a link

Comment: @Jarla it is the exactly the same process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just use CSS to remove the background and border

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button name ="sort" value="sort" type="submit">&#9660;</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only properties of the button which are visible are `background` and `border`. So you have to set these properties to nothing like the following code:

```css
button {
  background:none;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<button name ="sort" value="sort" type="submit">&#9660;</button>
```

> **Hint:** If you want to define the rule only for this button you have to replace `button` with `button[name="sort"]` or set a class.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button name ="sort" value="sort" type="submit" style="background-color:transparent;border:0">&#9660;</button>
```