# how to create a Codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, friendly-url

I have a CodeIgniter website and the link structure for the inner pages look like below:

http://www.example.com/pages/Campus-Tour/18/3

pages is my controller name and campus-tour, 18 and 3 are the values passed into the index method.

I want to make a pretty url, so can I use something like this in routes.php?

```
$route['campus-life/campus-tour'] = 'pages/Campus-Tour/18/3';
```

to show this URL "http://www.example.com/campus-life/campus-tour"

Answer (score 0):

Please use this syntax for routing.

```
$route['string-that-you-want-to-show-in-url'] = 'controller/function/arg1/arg2';
```

**Example --**

```
$route['campus-life/campus-tour'] = 'pages/campus_tour/$1/$2';
```

***Note:- PHP doesn't support hyphen(-) inside function name, your function name (Campus-Tour) is invalid, please check it & use the above syntax.***

Answer (score 0):

> **FYI:** A valid function name ***starts with a letter*** or ***underscore***, ***followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.***

---

If you transmit data URL with this to `pages/Campus-Tour/18/3` this `campus-life/campus-tour` it's clearly missing your URL parameter as you can see.

What you can do is `<form>` submit with `POST` and in the function, you can catch those.

**In View**

```
<form action ="campus-life/campus-tour" method ="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_param" value = "18"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="second_param" value = "3"/>
    <input type="submit"> # make this a No button. Should looks like <a> tag. Use CSS. (check Link)
</form>
```

**In Controller**

```
function Name() #add valid function/controller name
{
    # catch the POST values
}
```

Reference : [How to make a button look like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368286/4595675)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the syntax for routing. Please use this:

```
$route['pages/Campus-Tour/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/campus-tour/$1/$2';
```