# How to show popup on clicking link in angular js

Tags: angular

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="delete()" confirm-if="checked" confirm="Are you sure, {{name}}?">Delete</button>
```

this is working for button and i am able to get popup but for link, it is not working fine.Following is my code

```
 i want the confirm popup on clicking the link instead of button
<a ng-click="delete()" confirm-if="checked" confirm="Are you sure you want to delete it anyhow?">delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of the button that works to look like a link. Detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368286/5048820).

HTML:

```
<button class="link-button" type="button" ng-click="delete()" confirm-if="checked" confirm="Are you sure, {{name}}?">Delete</button>
```

CSS:

```
.link-button {
 background:none!important;
 color:inherit;
 border:none; 
 padding:0!important;
 font: inherit;
 /*border is optional*/
 border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
 cursor: pointer;
```

}