# django how to create a sign out link with template?

Tags: html, css, django

I have tried this:

```
 .sign-out {
        height: 21px;
        width: 168px;
        color: #0854B3;
        font-family: Averta, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 17px;
        margin-left: 291px;
    }

<html>
...
    <form method="post" action="{% url logout %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="sign-out" type="submit">sign out</div>
    </form>
<html>
```

However the sign out text isn't clickable -- how do I make it so?

Comment: Replace `<div>` with `<button>`?

Comment: You need to give url like this `"{% url 'logout' %}"`

Comment: @willemVanOnsem but I'm required to make it a text clickable, not a button

Comment: @nz_21: you can simply alter a button to show the text: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1367409/67579

Comment: @nz_21: note that HTML is more a *semantical* layer, usually CSS determines how something looks. HTML is more to put "structure" into the data, and make it convenient to style it.

Answer (score 1):

You basically made two errors here:

1. in order to submit a form, the element to submit the form should be an `<input>` or `<button>` type, or you need to use some JavaScript to submit the form; and
2. an `{% url ... %}` template tag expects as first parameter the name of the view, so a string.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="sign-out" type="submit">sign out</button>
</form>
```

You can style the button as text with:

```
.sign-out {
    background:none!important;
    border:none; 
    padding:0!important;
    height: 21px;
    width: 168px;
    color: #0854B3;
    font-family: Averta, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 291px;
}
```