# How to make a column value in Mat-Table a hyperlink

Tags: angular

I have a mat-table in which I have to put a hyperlink on each column value of the table and pass the id value to the API. For that I tried wrapping the column value inside  tag but that didn't work .

<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
ID

<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.projectId}} 

I then tried to test using a button in that place and passing the id on (click) event and it worked . But i want it to be be hyperlink tag , not a button .

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                    ID
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><button (click)="sendCall(row.Id)">{{row.Id}}</button> </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

But I want it to look something like this and be able to pass the value on click -
Can anyone please help on this ?

Comment: Did you try with 
<a (click)="sendCall(row.sbId)">{{row.projectId}}</a>

Comment: Use `(click)="sendCall(row.sbId)"` instead of `onclick`. onclick is javascript function, `click` is angular

Comment: Hi @NikhilWalvekar , i tried (click) also , but i dont get that hyperlink sign on the row .

Comment: @AnandSrivastava To use hyperlink in mat-table you can check the link in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-cell-mat-table?file=app%2Ftable-basic.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why'd you need the `click` event handler in the `<a>` tag? You could just bind to `href` attribute.

Try the following

```html
<a href="/someRoute/{{row.Id}}">{{row.rowId}}</a>
```

Comment: Because i need to pass that ID to an API to fetch data for each row clicked . I dont have to open a link or something , href opens a new link .

Comment: Then I'd say anchor tag is not the right choice. You can use `<button>` and style it to look like a link. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368286/6513921

Comment: This looks better . thanks